# Fullcalendar - отобразить количество записей в таблице для дней календаря

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин

Кто сталкивался с такой задачей? Нужно для каждого дня календаря - вывести в ячейке количество записей за этой за это число

Comment: Я сталкивался. Покажи, что ты сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(.....) from ..... group by ....
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html
- http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html